# How do I write arbitrary text to the console in a spock test?

Tags: groovy, spock, jenkins-spock

While writing tests I sometimes just want to write text to the console for debugging.

How do I do this in a spock test? I tried using the logger but it's throwing an error:

```
import javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslScriptLoader
import javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.JenkinsJobManagement
import org.junit.ClassRule
import org.jvnet.hudson.test.JenkinsRule
import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

import java.util.logging.Logger

class JobScriptsSpec extends Specification {
    @Shared
    @ClassRule
    JenkinsRule jenkinsRule = new JenkinsRule()

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("")

    @Unroll
    def 'test script #file.name'(File file) {
        given:
        def jobManagement = new JenkinsJobManagement(System.out, [:], new File('.'))

        when:
        new DslScriptLoader(jobManagement).runScript(file.text)

        then:
        noExceptionThrown()

        where:
        // This throws an error
        logger.info ("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz")
        file << jobFiles
    }

    static List<File> getJobFiles() {
        List<File> files = []
        new File('jobs').eachFileRecurse {
            if (it.name.endsWith('.groovy')) {
                files << it
            }
        }
        files
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend to give your questions some more love and not just say "it's throwing an error" but also quote the error. I did that for you in my answer, but actually it should be part of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groovy behaves no different from Java in this regard. For the most part Groovy is a superset of Java syntax. So you can write `System.out.println("hey")` or do it the groovy way `println "hey"`.

Using loggers is also fine. Maybe you should not log anything in the `where:` block because there Spock expects your data tables or data providers, not procedural code. Put the code into the block where it belongs, i.e. anywhere else but `where:`. Your `logger.info "hey"` should not even compile and the error you see should be:

```
Error:(18, 5) Groovyc:
  where-blocks may only contain parameterizations
  (e.g. 'salary << [1000, 5000, 9000]; salaryk = salary / 1000')
```

---

P.S.: Having seen your last two questions, I really recommend to first read a Groovy tutorial and then the Spock manual before asking more questions. No offence meant, I just want to help you help yourself.